# Store rating as an integer - android

Tags: java, android, rating

In my android app, I have to ask the user to rate it (stars icon, 4 stars). If a user rates 2 stars, I need to convert it as value 2(int type) and store it at back-end (Salesforce).

And also while displaying the summary, I need to get the int value and display as 1,2,3 or 4 stars.

How do I approach this task?

Any help with code or suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RatingBar widget in Android to display a star-rating bar to the user, and then use the getNumStars() method to get the number of stars shown as an int. Details here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html

Comment: Thanks. It's helpful. Do you know, how can I convert the int value back to stars (rating) while showing it in summary.

Comment: Sure thing. You can use setNumStars(int numStars) to convert an int value back to stars.